# reducing my ios application size

Tags: ios, optimization, filesize

I am developing my first app (iOS universal app), I want to reduce my app's size because it contains many images (png files) and sounds(mp3 files).

So my problem is:
How can I reduce the size of my app (images and sounds)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Images:

- Only include the basics in your app bundle (i.e. app icons, launch image, and possibly images for the first page)
- Use Parse (or any other similar service) to download any additional images *after* the app is downloaded.

This approach will significantly decrease the size of your app but also let you pull down additional image files as needed.

Sounds:

- What is the type of sounds files you're using? .caf files are incredibly large. Using .aifc files are just as good quality (to my untrained ear at least) and takes up significantly less space

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I am developing my application using cocos2dx and not native solution so my question now is: Can I use Parse with cocos2dx ?

Comment: I've never used cocos2dx but I would imagine so. Parse is a remote data store that you pull data from using web services. So to answer your question, if you can use AFNetworking in your app then you can use Parse. You can checkout details at www.parse.com

Answer (score 0):

Depends, compress png images to jpeg usually reduce app size, there are also [image optimizers](https://imageoptim.com) that compress pngs. If your images are part of the UI, tile them or stretch them really helps you in reduce app size and also memory usage. The image asset function in Xcode 5 helps in you in create resizable images.
For sounds the concept are pretty close to images, use compressed file audio as eckyzero said.
If your sounds and images aren't part of the UI but resources, you can make the app download them from the internet at first launch.